# Net and week*-topology

Tags: general-topology

I was reading Haim Brezis and came across a small remark. It makes me become unsure of my understanding of definition of nets in topology.

**The remark**:*With $E=l^{\infty}$ , the unit ball $B_{E^*}$ is compact with respect to its weak-$*$ topology, while we can construct a sequence in $B_{E^*}$ that don't have a convergent subsequence .*

This mark reminds me of a result in topology:

**Theorem** : *A topological space X is compact iff every net has a convergent subnet*  **(1)**

So , I tried to deduce something like below:

"For any $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \in B_{E^*}$.
 We have that $B_{E^*}$ is compact with respect to its weak-$*$ topology.
 Hence, by theorem (1), we get that, there is a convergent subsequence $(x_{n_k})_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$.
Which is wrong.So I was wrong in some parts"

Can you help me figure out what I did wrong?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

A subnet of a sequence is not necessarily a subsequence.

EDIT: For an example, see e.g. [this question and answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1209341/example-of-converging-subnet-when-there-is-no-converging-subsequence/1209702#1209702).

Comment: Thank you, it helps me a lot