# $A$ closed and $B$ compact $\implies \exists U$ open convex and balanced with $(A + U) \cap (B + U) = \emptyset$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces, locally-convex-spaces, nets

Let $X$ be a topological vector space, a set $U \subset X$ is said to be balanced if $\lambda u \in U$ for any $u \in U$ and $\lambda \in [-1,1]$

I would like to prove the following theorem

Theorem
Let $X$ be a topological locally convex vector space, let $A \subset X$ closed, $B \subset X$ compact such that $A \cap B = \emptyset$, then there exists a open convex balanced set $U$ containing $0$ such that
$(A + U) \cap (B + U) = \emptyset$

This is the proof of the theorem when $X$ has a norm $||\,||$

Proof

Suppose by contradiction that $(A + B(0,\epsilon) ) \cap (B + B(0,\epsilon) ) \neq \emptyset$ for any $\epsilon > 0$.
Let $\epsilon_n \downarrow 0$, let $x_n \in (A + B(0,\epsilon_n) ) \cap (B + B(0,\epsilon) )$
Then there exists $a_n \in A$, $b_n \in B$, $y_n,z_n \in B(0,\epsilon_n)$ such that

$x_n = a_n + y_n = b_n + z_n$

Since $B$ is compact $(b_n)$ as a convergent subsequence, WLOG I can assume that $(b_n)$ itself is convergent.

Since $a_n = b_n + (z_n - y_n)$ and $||z_n - y_n|| \leq ||z_n|| + ||y_n|| \leq 2\epsilon_n$ I have that $(a_n - b_n)$ converges to $0$, therefore $a_n$ is convergent and it's limit is the same of $(b_n)$, but, since the limit of $(a_n)$ is in $A$ ($A$ is closed ) and the limit of $(b_n)$ is in $B$ I have that $A \cap B$ is non-empty, a contradiction.

I tried to generalize this proof to the general case, this is what I came up with :

[image: Part 1 of the proof]

[image: Part 2 of the proof]

Is the proof actually correct? If it is, can it be generalized to the case where $X$ is not $T2$?If it's not, why? and is there a way to "fix" the mistakes in the proof?

Comment: I find this proof correct. More generally (Bourbaki, General Topology, chap. II, § 4.3) in a uniform space $X$, for disjoints subsets $A$ compact and $B$ closed, there exists an entourage $V$ such that $V(A)\cap V(B)=\varnothing.$ Your Theorem 1 then results from your Lemma 1, without assuming $X$ is T2. Lemma 1 is immediate with the definition of locally convex t.v.s. by semi-norms.

Comment: @AnneBauval the thing I'm not sure about is if I can say that the net $(b_U)_{U \in \mathcal{D}}$ has a converging subnet and if the limit of that subnet is in $B$. This would clearly be true when $X$ has a norm because in that case compact $\implies$ sequentally compact and closed, but since $X$ doesn't have a norm is this true?

Comment: For *every* topological space $B$ (even not T2), convergence (to a point *in $B$*) of some subnet for every net [is equivalent to compactness of $B.$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_(mathematics)#Characterizations_of_topological_properties) (Hence different from sequential compactness: neither stronger nor weaker. Except of course if $B$ is metrizable.)

Comment: FYI - you can use `\| v \|` to get a nicer looking norm instead of `|| v ||`: $\|v\|$ vs $||v||$.

Comment: @AnneBauval but a sequence is also a net so this would imply that every compact is also sequentually compact. Where am I wrong?

Comment: [A subnet of a sequence is not necessarily a subsequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2150490).