# Nets and sequences in a 1st couuntable space.

Tags: general-topology, nets

Let $(X,\mathcal{T}$) be a 1st countable topological space. Let $(x_\delta)_{\delta\in\Delta}$ be a net converging to $x$. Does there exist a sequence $(x_n)$ that converges to $x$ and which is a subnet of $(x_\delta)$? Any feedback is most appreciated?

Answer (score 1):

Certainly not.  Even if the net $(x_\delta)$ has the amazing property $x_\delta = x$ for all $\delta$.  Even then, it may have no subsequences at all.

Comment: I have no idea of set theory, but is the hypothesis $|\Delta| \geq |\Bbb N|$ (in some precisely defined sense that I'm not totally sure of) what we'd need?

Comment: An example for this is $\Delta = \omega_1$, the least uncountable ordinal.

Comment: In which case there do exist subnets, right?

Comment: Thanks you for your comments, but can you tell me under what conditions will a net have a subnet which is a sequence that converges to the same limit. Also under what are the sufficient and necessary conditions for a top space to be characterized by it's convergent sequence?  Thanks again I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Hendrik: You should ask these as new questions, instead of appending them as a comment here where very few people will see them.  But first you may wish to read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_space

Comment: This depends on which definition of *subnet* you use. If you use the nicest one, due to Aarnes and Andenæs, every constant net has the corresponding constant sequence as a subnet and hence as a subsequence. All three are discussed in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1126950/12042).