# Does every net have a countable subnet?

Tags: general-topology, nets

I was wondering whether a  net always has a countable subnet? Since there is a criterion for continuity using nets, and in some spaces we can check only for sequences. It would seem to me that a convergent net to a point with a countable local base we can find, but is this even true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  The net on $\omega_1$ into $\omega_2,$ sending each
countable ordinal to itself is a counter example.

If a net converges to a point p with countable
local base, then yes, there is a countable subnet.

Let { $U_1, U_2,$ ... } be the countable base and use
the decending local base { $U_1, U_1 \cap U_2,$ ... }
to construct a countable subnet.

Comment: You mean with the order topology, right?

Comment: Yes, with the usual topology for the ordinals.  @Keen-ameteur

Comment: The general definition of a subnet is the first in the: [[https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1126609/different-definitions-of-subnet]]

Comment: If $(0,1]$ is taken with the reverse order, then $(0,1]\times \omega_1$ is taken with the product order is a directed set. If $\phi:\omega_1\to[0,2\pi)$ is a bijection, then $x:(0,1]\times\omega_1\to\mathbb{C}$ defined by $x(a,b)=ae^{i\phi(b)}$ is a net that converges to zero in the usual topology of $\mathbb{C}$. This net doesn't have a countable subnet even though it goes to a metric space (in particular with countable local base) and converges.

Comment: @William Elliot; When X is with countable local base, your answer is false because of: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3448778/does-every-net-in-mathbbc-converging-to-0-have-a-countable-subnet